# Is USER_NAME column unique in HANA DB USERS table?

Tags: hana

Is USER_NAME field/column unique in HANA Database USERS table? I am seeing just number in USER_ID values.

Like BNAME in SAP USR02 table, I want to know what is the unique(or equivalent to bname) value field in HANA DB USERS table.

Comment: Ram are you referring to the user table in sys schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amandeep Modgil's answer is not wrong but does not fully answer the question.

Of course, the documentation makes it clear that user names in SAP HANA need to be unique. However, it does not specifically explain whether or how this is enforced/guaranteed.

The "DB dev way" to find out something like this is to check the table structure used by HANA to store users.

Looking at the `PUBLIC.USERS` objects, we realize: this is not a table but a **view** instead.

Views don't have any constraints assigned to them, so any *primary key* or *unique* constraint must be implemented with one of the tables referenced by the view.

The next step is to review the source code for the view. In SAP HANA Studio one can simply mark the name of the view in the SQL editor and choose **"Show Definition"** from the context menu.

For `PUBLIC.USERS` this opens two(!) new windows:

- one for the public synonym (there really is no `PUBLIC` schema, just synonyms) for `USERS`
- and another one for the view `SYS.USERS`

This `SYS` schema is where SAP HANA system objects are implemented, so it's not surprising to find the view for `USERS` here.

In my HANA Express 2.00.045 system, the source code for the view surprisingly begins with

```
CREATE **ROW TABLE** "SYS"."USERS" ( "USER_NAME",
     "USER_ID",
     "USERGROUP_NAME" ...
```

That's *weird* at the very least, and I suspect it might be a bug as all other metadata entries for this object make it clear that this is in fact a view.

But I digress...

The question to answer was: where is the uniqueness of `USER_NAME` enforced?
Scrolling down the last main `FROM`-clause of the `SYS.USERS`-view points to a table: `SYS.P_USERS_`.

The trailing underscore in the name indicates that this is an **internal** HANA object that should never be directly used by any user or application. But that does not stop us from looking at it. Appropriate privileges are required for that, though. The "normal" application user account probably won't be able to directly look at this table's definition. I'm just using the `SYSTEM` user in this case.

Anyhow, we use the same technique as before: mark the `SYS.P_USERS_` table in the SQL Editor, choose "Show definition" and we get: the definition of the table that holds the user accounts in SAP HANA.

The first three columns are defined like this:

```
Name                    SQL Data Type   Dimension   Column Store Data Type  Key Not Null
OID                     BIGINT                      FIXED                       X
NAME                    NVARCHAR        256         STRING
LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CONNECT TIMESTAMP                   LONGDATE ...
```

Notice how there is **no** primary key defined on this table and how only `OID` has a `NOT NULL` constraint?

Clearly, the uniqueness of `NAME` is not guaranteed by table constraints.
So what else could it be?

Let's switch to the `Indexes` tab of the table definition and we find:

- `IDX_P_USERS_OID`, indexed columns: `"OID" ASC`
- `IDX_P_USERS_NAME`, index columns: `"NAME" ASC`

**AND** for both of these indexes the **`Unique`-flag** is set.

And there we have it:
Both `OID` (exposed as `USER_ID`) and `NAME` (exposed as `USER_NAME`) are unique in SAP HANA, enforced by unique indexes on the internal table that holds these user account entries.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your explanation in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the schema information on SAP portal link below:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/21026099751910148e0cdbddc75652b8.html

Although it does not tell you whether a particular column is the primary key or need to be unique, but you can combine this information with the data from following system view and get the information you are after.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.05/en-US/210197377519101481cfb213f0b84848.html

I have highlighted the columns in the tables system view you need in the screenshot below

[image: sap hana table system view screenshot]

Comment: from above schema details you should be able to map whether the user_name column is unique or not